# Pycharm runtime: No Python at dir\that\doesnt\exist

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

I had Anaconda installed as well as Python3 and this was causing some conflicts. I removed Anaconda and ensured my PATH variables all point to the Python3 install at `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32`

I have opened a project in PyCharm and set the python interpreter to that very path: no venv in case it was causing problems.

However, when CTRL+SHIFT+F10 to run it states `No Python at 'C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\python.exe'`

I have googled this for the past two hours and all I'm finding is "you haven't installed Python" or "set up the PyCharm interpreter to point to the python executable" which I have done.
I have even reinstalled Pycharm.

Please can someone suggest what I am doing wrong? There is no sign of Anaconda in the system or in the PyCharm terminal interpreter/project interpreter Thanks.

#### Edit:

Forgot to mention, in the `Project > Python Interpreter` settings I can see the interpreter and all the packages just fine. On the face of it: Everything is working fine. But run-time is giving me the anaconda install dir error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what caused this problem but it resolved itself. Sorry I cannot offer any insights.

Comment: Please let us know if it occurs again! It'll be useful should anyone else find a similar issue with PyCharm on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting pycharm once...if not your System..Comment here if it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Did not solve the issue. Even a reinstall of PyCharm didn't solve it. Cheers.

Comment: what system do you use...windows ,linux ..can you try and open python console from terminal??

Comment: I use windows 10 and python executes fine from terminal. Thanks.

Comment: C:\Users\JohnS\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2020.2-backup  go to path like this in you system and check if there is any backup file there. Basically you have everything in place ,just your pycharm configuration is messed up...Just try to restore everything to default configuration in your pycharm..

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issues as well when loading in projects using venvs.  My issue is that I would share projects across devices while working on them and my install location for python varied from device to device.

I fixed this issue by modifying the pyenv.cfg file using a text editor - I like Notepad++ - for the correct path/to/python.exe.  Note that there are a few lines in the cfg file that will need to be edited: home, base-prefix, base-exec-prefix, and base-executable.

Comment: Why edited?  I'm new to this, so just curious...